# One line to check to see if an property is an object and then fill with value

Tags: javascript, object

I currently have the following code which checks to see if a property is nullish, if it is I create an empty object, and then "push" a value into that object on the next line.

```js
const a = {};

a.b ??= {};
a.b.c= 1;

console.log(a)
```

I am curious if JS supports this operation with a single line of code.

Note that it is important that IF `b` already is an object with data that that data is preserved when `a.b.c` is set.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you keep your code as two lines for readability, but you *could* just stuff the first line into an if statement. However do keep in mind that if `a.b` is falsey (`0`, `""`, `false`), then this hack will fail.

```js
const a = {};

// if nullish, {} is truthy, otherwise, any object is still truthy
if (a.b ??= {}) a.b.c = 1;

// make some changes
a.b.d = 2;
a.b.c = 3;

// doesn't "reset" the property if it does exist
if (a.b ??= {}) a.b.c = 1;

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wanted Object.assign() with the null assignment operator inside the first argument.

```js
const a = {b: {z: 2}};
Object.assign(a.b ??= {}, {c: 1})
console.log(a)

const a2 = {};
Object.assign(a2.b ??= {}, {c: 1})
console.log(a2)
```